# What is the best approach in ArcGIS Pro to fill a field with 3 different values based on 3 rows matching the same value of another field?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

I have 'cross sections' that are divided into 3 polygons per cross section. These 3 polygons have a field which they share the same value (a float), which is unique from the values of other cross section 3 polygons. I am looking to fill a new blank field I have made with 'Left', 'Center', and 'Right' values. They don't necessarily need to be accurately labeled position-wise, as long as there is one 'Left', one 'Center', and one 'Right' per 3 polygon cross section. I believe using the 'Calculate Field' tool is the objective, but I am finding no luck.

I'm imagining there's a way to write some python function that checks for the shared value (each shared value appears 3 times (3 rows)) and on first appearance of a value assign 'Left', second appearance assign 'Center', third appearance assign 'Right'.